# C# генерация случайного пути

Tags: c#

У меня есть двумерный массив целых чисел. В данном массиве есть точка входа [0,0] , а так же  точка выхода [Length-1,Length-1]. (Это квадрат, матрица, если можно так назвать).
Мне нужно сгенерировать случайный путь с точки входа в точку выхода и заполнить этот путь числом 98. (Прошу заметить, не самый короткий, а просто случайный). Подкиньте идею, как реализовать.

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под путем и какие на нем ограничения?

Comment: Насколько случайный? Можно двигаться в любую сторону или только к выходу? Путь сам себя может пересекать? Если самый простой вариант - бросать монетку, если орел, то двигаться вправо, решка - вниз. Как достигнем границы (нижней или правой), то идти прямо к выходу

Comment: @tym32167 Можно двигатся в любую сторону , может сам себя пересекать. Но обязательно должен попасть к выходу.

Comment: Значит вам нужен алгоритм генерации лабиринта, его описание вроде есть в Википедии (с телефона гуглить неудобно, найдете сами)

Comment: @tym32167 Хорошо, благодарен.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/82059

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Благодарен за ссылку.

Comment: Ну тогда уж добьем [ссылками на русском](https://tproger.ru/articles/maze-generators/) :)

Comment: Статья в [вики на англ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нет никаких ограничений на то, в какой мере путь может пересекать или накладываться на себя, случайный путь - это просто набор случайных точек. Напишем код для заполнения линии между двумя точками:

```
public class Map
{
    int[,] cells;

    public Map(int size)
    {
        cells = new int[size, size];                
    }

    //заполнение прямой между двумя точками заданным числом
    public void FillLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int value)
    {

        int x = x1, y = y1;
        int dx = Math.Sign(x2 - x1); //приращение по X
        int dy = Math.Sign(y2 - y1); //приращение по Y
        bool direction_y = false;

        while (true)
        {
            cells[x, y] = value;                    

            if (x == x2 && y == y2) break; //достигнута конечная точка

            //сделаем по очереди приращение по X или Y
            if (direction_y)
            {
                if (y != y2) y += dy;
            }
            else
            {
                if (x != x2) x += dx;
            }
            direction_y = !direction_y;

        }

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(500);

        for (int y = 0; y < cells.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < cells.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0} ",cells[x,y].ToString().PadLeft(2));

            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Тогда заполнение случайного пути будет выглядеть так:

```
const int SIZE = 30; 
const int N = 4; 

Map m = new Map(SIZE);
Random rnd = new Random();            
int x0=0,y0=0,x, y;
int value = 1;

//проходим через N случайных точек
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    x = rnd.Next(SIZE-1);
    y = rnd.Next(SIZE-1);
    m.FillLine(x0, y0, x, y,value);
    x0 = x;
    y0 = y;
}

//заходим в конец
x = SIZE - 1;
y = SIZE - 1;
m.FillLine(x0, y0, x, y, value);
```